# How can I run Java 8 code on eclipse 4.2?

Tags: java-8, xtext, eclipse-juno

For a project I need to get Java 8 to work on eclipse 4.2 because I want to work with an eclipse plugin that requires XText 2.3.1 and modify code that requires java 8 functionality.

I have tried later versions of eclipse, however those later versions are incapable of running xtext 2.3.1 and the required plugin. Is there some way of getting java 8 code to run on eclipse juno?

Comment: Xtext 2.3 is from 2012, Java 8 from 2014, any specific reason you stick to old Xtext / Eclipse and or new Java 8?

Comment: Yes. I am adding functionality to a program using java 8. The plugin used to add this functionality requires the old version of xtext to function.

Comment: and writing your code in java 7 is not possible? i think a migration to a newer Xtext, e.g. the one from luna is easier than teaching and old eclipse a java version that was not out when the Eclipse was released